# custom admin module edit data not working properly

Tags: php, magento

I am creating custom admin module where grid, edit, new, delete work as same as product grid. Everything working fine but when i click on grid row to edit item it redirects correctly but the all pages value is blank.

If you need any page please ask me here i can post the pages here

[image]

Comment: Check if the ID and necessary data is being passed in your `editAction()`

Answer (score 1):

Normally in edit pages there is a form container, which contains a form, which has a method something like this:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(/* ...stuff... */);
    $fieldset->addField(/* ...much more stuff... */);
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
}
```

Without seeing any code I cannot guess what you have named things but at some point after adding fields you must also do:

```
    $model = Mage::registry('some model you registered in a controller');
    $form->setValues($model);
```